# How to access CISCO Tapi from .Net Application

Tags: c#, c++

I am new to Tapi. Please apologizes me, if anything is wrong or not clear.

I need a c++ wrapper for accessing cisco Tapi from my application (Developed in .net 3.0 with c#) I Searched on web, I got free wrapper and sample code like (Julmar Itapi and Atapi and Helan warn wrapper). These wrappers are  used access the Microsoft Tapi 2.1 and 3.0.

But what I am searching is, How to access CISCO Tapi from my .net application. Is there any free wrapper available to access CISCO Tapi? I didn't get any information and other related links from web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records: It's called [ATAPI.NET](https://github.com/markjulmar/atapi.net).